# Simple Spring URL Handling?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC for an application I am building. Everything is working fine, but what I do not know how to do is a simple link with Spring. Currently, I have everything mapped with a *.htm to a controller. This all works fine because they have controllers to handle them.

What I am not sure how to do is a simple link where there is an anchor tag that has a .jsp link, and it just goes to that page, and needs no form processing.

I know this is a very basic question, but I just want to know the easiest way to configure this.

And if this is not possible, and all links must go through a controller, I would like to know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to do is make sure you don't have a Spring DispatcherServlet mapped to the root of the application context.  e.g., if your Dispatcher is mapped to `/*` change it to `/pages/*` or something.  A dispatcher sitting on the root will "eat" any requests for regular resources.  (Alternately you could customize it to pass through for static resources, but that's I think beyond the scope of the question.)  Then if you just put a jsp file in your `webapp/whatever` folder (not `/WEB-INF`, the level above it.)  You should be able to navigate to it normally.

```
/webapp/whatever/index.jsp

/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
```

web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Should result in being able to go to `http://soisawesome.com/app/whatever/index.jsp` as well as `/pages/controllerhandledform.htm`